# dynamically create a php class name on the fly

Tags: php, class

I am new to OOPs. I have a class that i want to dynamically create.

```
 class ByDynamicClassName implements GridTemplate
 .....
```

How can I create a new name on the fly. Basically I have created my own grid system but what to create multiple grids on one page I need to call a new class name.

I would like to be able to do specify a php variable in the class name as like this class $dynamic_name implements GridTemplate but naturally that would not work.

Is there any way of defining class names on the fly.

Comment: “OOPs” is definitely the word. I’m not sure what you’re trying to achieve. If you have a class, you can instantiate multiple instances of it; you don’t need to create a new class for each new instance.

Comment: If you're new to OOP, understand now that what you want to do is a) not really possible in a sane way and b) a very bad idea. Stop this now and go on using OOP in established, traditional ways.

Comment: maybe i am mixing functions and classes incorrectly. But I have a function that calls a class function grid_insert_template($grid_name,$action)
{
 //Insert temlate
 $grid = $grid_name; 
 
 //add Function
 if ($action == "add" || $action == "add_edit")
 {  
  class MyInsertTemplate implements GridTemplate
  {